# System menus disappear when I maximize a child window

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi, cview

Has anybody encountered this issue?

I am using MFC on an MDI application. I switch between menus using SetMenu() but has the side effect of system menus (Maximize, Minimize, Close buttons) disappearing when I maximize the child windows.

```
CMenu* pMenu = GetMenu();
if (pMenu == NULL) return;
pMenu->Detach();

// Reset application menu
CMenu newMenu;
newMenu.LoadMenu(menuID);
SetMenu(&newMenu);
```

If I don't call SetMenu(), the issue does not happen.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> CMenu newMenu;
> newMenu.LoadMenu(menuID);
> SetMenu(&newMenu);
> ```

`newMenu` is a temporary object. It will be destroyed as soon as the function exits. The result is undefined behavior.

> ```
> CMenu* pMenu = GetMenu();
> if (pMenu == NULL) return;
> pMenu->Detach();
> ```

I am not sure what this code will accomplish. Note that `CWnd::SetMenu` will replace the old menu. It will not destroy the old menu handle, but MFC will handle the clean up at the end (`Detach` will not destroy the handle if that was the goal)

---

Try this code instead:

Declare menu objects as class member:

```
class CMainFrame : public CMDIFrameWnd
{
    CMenu m_menu1, m_menu2;
    ...
};
```

Load the menu once:

```
CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
{
    m_menu1.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1);
    m_menu2.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU2);
    ...
}
```

Change menu:

```
void CMainFrame::OnChangeMenu()
{
    if(want_menu1)
    {
        SetMenu(&m_menu1);
    }
    else if (want_menu2)
    {
        SetMenu(&m_menu2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something different: Just use the menu management functionality as originally intended by MFC. For a typical MDI MFC application, you don't really need to do anything with menus (and I mean these calls to `SetMenu()`). Only define them, and MFC will do the rest for you.

More specifically, a Wizard-generated MDI application contains the following menus:

- `IDR_MAINFRAME`, which will be displayed when there exists no MDI child window (open document). Typically contains the *File*, *View* and *Help* submenus.
- `IDR_DocType`, one for each document-type you have defined. This is displayed when a MDI child window displaying a document of this type is the active one. Typically contains the *File*, *Edit*, View, *Window* and *Help* submenus.

Please note that:

- You only have to define/edit these menus, eg add more commands or
  even more submenus. You don't need to switch menus, the framework
  will do this for you.
- The framework will NOT merge submenus or menu items, it will instead just select `IDR_MAINFRAME` or one of the `IDR_DocType` ones, depending on the MDI child window currently active.
- Consequently, some of the submenus or items may be duplicates (albeit not necessarily exact copies), some others not. For example, the *View* submenu for `IDR_MAINFRAME` typically contains two menu items, *Toolbar* (or *Toolbars*) and *Status Bar* (toggling display of the toolbar and status bar), while the doctype-specific ones typically contain the above, plus some additional ones, determining how to display the document; eg if the document is an image, you would normally add some display choices like *1:1*, *Fit To Width*, *Fit To Height* and *Best Fit* (in a radio-button setting), shown above the *Toolbar* and *Status Bar* ones, separated with a separator menu-item.

I have developed many such applications, and never had to use `SetMenu()`. I would suggest that you first restore the `IDR_MAINFRAME` and `IDR_DocType` menus to their original state, and then put in any additional/custom ones. If you have destroyed or changed significantly the menus originally generated by the Wizard, you can create a new MFC project/solution with the same settings as yours, and copy-paste the menus in the resource file.